# Angular 5 EventEmitter from child to parent component emits undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to send a `string` from a child component to his parent component.

Here is the child :

```
//imports... 

    @Component({
    selector: 'child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
    providers: [ChildService]
    })

export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private childService : ChildService) {}

    myMap = new Map<string, ISomeInterface>();
    currentSelection: string;

    @Output() sendDataEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

    sendData() {
        console.log("sending this data:  " + this.myMap.get(this.currentSelection).name);
        this.sendDataEvent.emit(this.myMap.get(this.currentSelection).name);
    }
}
```

Here is the parent :

html ->

```
<d-table (sendDataEvent)="receiveBusinessCycle(event)"></d-table>
```

typescript ->

```
//imports...

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
  providers: [ParentService]
})
export class MyParentComponent {
  totoName: string;

  constructor(private parentService : ParentService) {  }

  receiveBusinessCycle($event) {
    console.log($event); //shows in console 'undefined'
    console.log($event as string); 
    this.totoName = $event;
  }

}
```

The issue is that I am getting an **undefined** event when receiving the data in the parent component, here console logs :

```
sending this data:  201808
main.bundle.js:2328 undefined
main.bundle.js:2329 undefined
```

Any ideas on the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using `$event` here:

```
<d-table (sendDataEvent)="receiveBusinessCycle($event)"></d-table>
```

I've faced a similar situation before and apparently, it seems to only work with `$event` as it is a reserved keyword to grab the event object.

Apparent, Angular provides a corresponding DOM event object in the `$event` only. That's why passing in any other variable as an argument won't work. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object).

Angular also considers this as a dubious practice when working with native HTML Elements as it breaks the separation of concerns between the template and the component. Angular recommends the use of Template Variables instead. Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice).

Answer (score 1):

You missed `$` prefix of the `event`. `$event` is a reserved word, so your data is visible to the event handler in the component markup only with name `$event`.

```
<d-table (sendDataEvent)="receiveBusinessCycle($event)"></d-table>
```